# (TYPO3 8.7.x) Update SYS_LASTCHANGED of a page on changing data in sysfolder

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x

I want to change the SYS_LASTCHANGED of a defined page, when I changed data at my sysfolder. My problem is, when I change the data at the sysfolder, my page with my plugin showing the data not updating the indexed data for indexed_search.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray` hook (or any other suitable one) of `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler` to change anything after a record has been saved.
Set your configuration (which page should be affected) in page TS of your sysfolder and use the `getTCEMAIN_TSconfig` method of `Datahandler` (you'll get an instance of that as parameter for the hook) to read it out and modify the desired page attribute.